# Uses update_attributes on an association/join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
membership = Membership.where(user_id: 1, group_id: 1).first
# some other code
membership.update_attributes(admin: true)
```

generates a query

```
UPDATE 'memberships' SET 'admin' = 1 WHERE 'memberships'.'' IS NULL
```

which results in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'memberships'.'' IS NULL` have to be `'memberships'.'id'=`

And there is no id in model I suppose.

Then the right way to update attribute will be something like that

```
membership = User.find(1).memberships.first
# some other code
membership.update_attributes(admin: true)
```

**UPDATE**

Seems adding the id to this model will be the best choice.

Comment: It generates the same sql with `update_attribute(:admin, true)`. See my question, the WHERE clause of the generated sql is invalid obviously.

Comment: Oh, you are right. There is no `id` column in the `memberships` table. Instead, it has a compound primary key `(user_id, group_id)`. I thought `id` is not needed for a join table so I set `id: false` in the migration. So it is necessary to put an `id` column even in a join table?

Comment: Seems adding the id to this model would be the best choice.